# Post ajax request with PHP script

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, ubuntu, selenium

I am trying to test an ajax post request that takes my formData object and runs it through a PHP script (I don’t know any PHP, but was provided with the script in the question).

So I have a PHP file called index.php on my local drive (I use Ubuntu), what's supposed to happen is I post the formData object and a report.txt file is created and is accessible by going to `http://copypaste.test`. I'm stuck on how to create the domain locally on my PC.

```
Selenium.prototype.doSaveCopyPaste = function(locator) {
 var text = jQuery(locator).text();

 var formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('report', text);

 var ajax = jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://copypaste.test',
  data: formData,
  dataType: 'text',
  processData: false, 
  contentType: false,
    success: function(){ 
      console.log('success'); 
    },
    error: function() {
     console.log('error'); 
    } 
  });
  console.log(ajax) 
 }
```

Comment: You will need to create a new vhost in ubuntu. Then add the domain to your hosts file, which should point to whatever IP your webserver is listening on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a web server running on your local machine that accepts incoming HTTP requests and executes your PHP script that uses the input data from your client/browser/JavaScript and sends a response back.

As #Esil Stavenga wrote, using XAMPP is an option.

It includes a web server (Apache) and a PHP interpreter.

Instead of accessing your local PC by a domain name (like http://copypaste.test)
you might have to enter its IP address into your browser/client.

Answer (score 2):

you can use any web server to setup a local server. some common ones are xampp, wampServer etc
 [this tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/blog/xampp-tutorial/) explains in well how to setup xampp